# how to sent array data as formdata angular 4

Tags: angular, http-post, angular-http

I tried to post an array of data is not sending to server:

webservice:

```
 deleteCategory() {
    return  this.http.post('http://www.demo/webapi/deletecategory', { 
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "Token " + this.token,
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        withCredentials: true
      }
      )
    }
```

in ts file

```
onDelete() {
      this.userService.deleteCategory().subscribe(response => {
      this.selectedArray = [];
     for (var i = 0; i< this.selection._selected.length; i++){
     this.selectedArray.push(this.selection._selected[i].category_id) ;
     console.log(' selected value:', this.selectedArray);

     }
    })
      }
```

in html

```
<button class="btn-danger pull-right" (click)="onDelete()" type="button"  >Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your `deleteCategory()` method is making a POST request to the specified endpoint with an empty request body.

Here is a simple example on how to include an array of objects in a POST request using Angulars HttpClient

```
this.http.post('some url', JSON.stringify(yourArrayOfObjects), {headers: ...})
```

If you wanted to send FormData (if for example you're uploading a file to a server)

```
 const frmData = new FormData();
 frmData.append("fileUpload", file)
 this.http.post('some url', frmData, {headers:...})
```

Comment: if you're using httpClient (not teh "old fasion" http) you neen't JSON.stringify

Answer (score 2):

You have to create `FormData` object and append you array in this object. It's looks like

```
function createFormData(yourArray) {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append(
    'keyName',
     new Blob( [ JSON.stringify( yourArray ) ], { type : 'application/json' } ) );
  return fd;
}
```