# Angular 6: SyntaxError: Unexpected token O in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse with valid JSON

Tags: json, angular, http-post

I am not sure whether my function is wrong, which should send data to the server, or the function on the server is wrong.
I looked up similar questions but the solution I adopted to my problem did not work.

My function looks like this:

```
postData(number){
   let array = JSON.stringify(this.locArr);
   return this.http.post<any>(this.url, array)
    .subscribe(),
    error => console.log("Error: ", error)
    }
```

JSON which is send:

```
[ 
  { 
      "id":222,
      "name":"Lars",
      "sLA":37
   },
  { 
      "id":223,
      "name":"Sim",
      "sLA":12
   }
]
```

All parameters like token etc. are received by the server function but the array I wrote above is null, although it is valid json.
I wonder why this error is occuring.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: this json is invalid . please check your json : https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: sorry,  I changed it, forgot to remove the coma. Now it should be valid json.

Comment: also you are posting an array to the server which is not valid json  or more like text.  you should be posting it as json object

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. The array above is valid json? I checked it with a validator, or do you mean something else?

Comment: I tried it with Object.assign and send it as a JSON object but it is still not working..

Comment: i believe you are using httpClientModule so then there is no need of this step `JSON.stringify(this.locArr);` you neen't JSON.stringify : for more details please check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48921063/how-to-sent-array-data-as-formdata-angular-4

Answer (score 0):

The local array will be converted into JSON automatically by Angular, you need not stringify or parse it.

```
postData(number){
    this.http.post<any>(this.url, this.locArr)
    .subscribe((data)=>{
        //code after receiving data from server
    },
        error => console.log("Error: ", error))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using httpClientModule so then there is no need of tyou need't `JSON.stringify`  remove this step `JSON.stringify(this.locArr);`
Also you need to send it as json object `{}` not json array `[]`

```
postData($locArr){ // pass the array to the service function
   let data = { data : $locArr}; // note that you have to post it as json object {} not []
   return this.http.post<any>(this.url,data);
}
```

Comment: @Cara please check this

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answere! I think it is a server side error. I will try it!